# Return through gateway depending on source

Tags: linux, firewall, gateway

We have a Linux webserver that is accessed interally on `192.168.2.1`.  It has a default gateway of `192.168.2.2`.  This gateway does not connect to the outside world.

We also have a public IP of `176.35.XXX.XXX`.  This is connected to a firewall on `192.168.2.6` which is then forwarded to `192.168.2.1`.  The problem is that the default gateway is unable to return a response when accessing via the public IP.

Is it possible, to tell the webserver that any traffic from `192.168.2.6` should be returned to `192.168.2.6` rather than `192.168.2.2`?

EDIT:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.1.9      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      172.16.1.9      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.16.1.0      172.16.1.9      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

EDIT2:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5                                      3
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTAB                                      LISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:1                                      0000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2223 state                                       NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:137
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:138
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:1                                      39
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:4                                      45
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3000 state                                       NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.2.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 state                                       NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.16.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  86.162.148.238       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-ho                                      st-prohibited
DROP       all  --  198.204.250.82       0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  82.147.12.249        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  82.147.12.247        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  82.147.12.248        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  151.231.210.146      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-ho                                      st-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight everything is OK in your infrastructure. All hosts are placed on the same subnet and it means that **your webserver do not use gateway to send traffic to 192.168.2.6**.

I think you need to configure properly your gateway with public ip. If your public gateway is Linux host then you need to **configure iptables masquerading** OR **allow input ESTABLISHED and RELATED connections**.

If you give a list of iptables rules on 192.168.2.6 host then i possibly can help you with it.

Comment: Hi Egor, I have run route -n on the server and added it as an edit to my question.  Is that what you need? I'm new to this.  Thanks

Comment: No. I need `iptables -L -n output` from 192.168.2.6 (if it is a linux host). Thx

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my original question again.  192.168.2.1 is the linux server, 192.168.2.6 is the firewall that the public IP connects to (176.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Comment: Very strange that your public server do not act as nat and there isn't rules that forward traffic to webserver on 192.168.2.1. You need to forward 80/443 port traffic from public interface to internal webserver

Comment: The public interface points to a firewall (192.168.2.6) which then forwards traffic to 192.168.2.1.  If I run a tcpdump on 192.168.2.1 I can see activity when the public interface is used.  However the response is currently kept internal.  Does that make sense? I need the response to route back to the firewall when the public interface is used